# Phpmyadmin run very slow

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i have made some DB use `Phpmyadmin`.I can run it well before, but after i try some complicated query it run very slow.

i must wait about 5 minutes to get the count result. But for the simple query it runs well.
Why its happen? Could I solve this problem?

How do i do that?

---

```
SELECT X.id,X.Line,X.Model,X.Lot_no,X.Lot_Quantity,
                          X.Merchandise AS Merchandise,
                          X.Merchandise-X.Lot_Quantity AS Balance
                   FROM(
                        SELECT A.Inspection_datetime,A.id,A.Line, A.Model,                  
                               A.Lot_no,B.Lot_Quantity,
                               IF(RIGHT(A.Range_sampling,4)='0000',10000,
                               RIGHT(A.Range_sampling,4))-MID(Range_sampling,5,4)+1 
                               AS Merchandise
                        FROM inspection_report A
                        LEFT JOIN prod_sch B
                        ON A.Line= B.Line_Name AND A.Model = B.Model_Code 
                        AND A.Lot_no= CONCAT(LPAD(CAST(B.Lot_No_ AS CHAR),3,'0'),'A')
                        WHERE MONTH(A.Inspection_datetime) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
                        AND YEAR(A.Inspection_datetime) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
                        GROUP BY A.Line, A.Model,A.Range_sampling) X
GROUP BY X.Model
```

Comment: You will need to show some table data, the query you are using and how many rows you are dealing with - dozens, thousands, millions?

Comment: Your problem is in the database, not in phpMyAdmin.  You should post the query code, perhaps we can help you to optimize it.

Comment: too much MYSQL keywords  
`IF`
`RIGHT`
`MID`
`CONCAT` 
`LPAD`
`CAST`
`MONTH`
`YEAR` just display your table structure and output result u want and the manner u want to extract tha data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does your query included `multiple join` and many `where condition`?? then u must create index on selected attributes which are used in `ON` and `WHERE` clause.

BTW... show your table structure as well as your Query...then can be give better solution

make **index** on following attributes in your table

> Line,Model,Lot_no,Inspection_datetime,range_sampling(
>   Table : insepection_report)
>   Line_Name,Model_code( Table: prod_sch
>   )

**Note:**

> try with EXPLAIN before SELECT and see the result

Comment: which SELECT? the 1st select or the 2nd?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running complex queries it is probably the underlying MySQL Database that is causing the delay, not phpMyAdmin.
You might want to optimize your queries or database structure.

Answer (score 0):

You needs to create [indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) on columns which are used in where clause to find the rows.

Indexes can do the thing fast.